# Probability...confused

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, independence

So, I'm struggling with this. Can anyone explain this in a non-statistical manner?

So I have a deck of cards and I take one out and the probability of it being a spades is 13/52 or 1/4 (Event A). Then, I want another spades and the probability is now 12/51 (Event B). So clearly B is dependent on A, but does that mean A is also dependent on B?

I mean, how is the first card dependent on the second card being drawn?

Comment: Dependence (in the probability sense) is non directional and acausal. You seem to be confusing causality with dependence.

Comment: The answer is 1/4 *12/51 for the P(A ) * P(B|A).  P(B)=1/4 and B depends on A because P(B|A) 12/51 which is not equal to P(B).  B depends on A.

Answer (score 2):

Dependence (in the probability sense) is non directional and acausal.

Independence would give us

$$P(AB) = P(A)\cdot P(B)\,.$$

Dependence is anything else ($P(AB) \neq P(A)\cdot P(B)\,$).

[Between variables, you can write a corresponding relationship (e.g. with their joint density being a product of the marginal densities for independence or not being the product for any kind of dependence).]

So if one variable depends on another, the second also depends on the first; specifically, if there's any dependence, they're dependent.

You seem to be confusing causality or perhaps physical dependence with statistical dependence there.

If you draw a card and hand it to Angela, and draw a second card and hand it to Bella and then Bella shows she had a spade, that information changes the probabilities for Angela's card (we have eliminated some of the possible spades from what it could be).

However, with cards specifically we can argue that there is physical dependence -- during shuffling, placing a particular spade into position 2 in the deck prevents you from putting it in position 1. You didn't influence anything when you drew card 1, but you had the physical dependence during the process of arranging cards into their positions in the shuffled deck.

Comment: The formula in the first sentence is only for independent events (as I'm sure you know), which doesn't seem to make sense in the context of the sentence about dependence. Is that what you intended to write?

Comment: Thanks Gordon; it omitted something I meant to put in there! I think it's okay now though

Answer (score 0):

The draw of the first card depends on the *existence* of the second card, not the *drawing* of the second card. The only role played by the second card is to supply sufficient alternative choices (or outcomes) that might or might not be the one you want; its only purpose is to provide choice. As a result, Event A constrains the choices available in Event B. Event A sends a small amount of probability information to Event B, but Event B cannot send information back to Event A.

You might like to read this paper by Alan Hájek:
 [Hájek, A. (2011). Conditional probability. Handbook of the Philosophy of Science, 7, 99-135.](http://philosophy.anu.edu.au/sites/default/files/Hajek%20-%20Conditional%20Probability.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help if you are more 'explicit' in the notation of your events: in your notion the narrative description of the events is that

- $A$ is the event: first card taken out is spades;
- $B$ is the event: given dat the first card is a spades, the second
  card taken is also spades,

To make the **notation for the second more explicit** I would notate your second event as $C|_A$, where $C$ is ''the second card is spades'' and so $C|_A$ is the event that the ''second is spades, given that the first was spades''.

To clearly understand your question this difference is very important: you are talking about the event $A$ and $B=C|_A$ while your statistics course probably states that states that

> $C$ (note that this is about $C$, **not** about $B=C|_A$) and $A$ are independent if $P(C|_A) = P(C)$ or the probability of
>   observing a value for $C$ does not depend on the outcome of the event
>   $A$.

In your example this is not the case:

$P(C)$ is the probability that the second card is spades and $P(C|_A)$ is the probability the probability that the second card is spades, given that the first was spades.  As $P(C)=13/52$ and $P(C|_A)=12/51$, $C$ and $A$ are dependent. If $C$ and $A$ are dependent then also $A$ and $C$ (see also the answer of @Glen_b).

> Note that the conclusion is that $C$ and $A$ are dependent, your
>   question is about the dependence of $B=C|_A$ and $A$ !

In order for $A$ and $C|_A$ to be independent we have to show that $P(B|_A)=P(B)$ or in the more explicit notation ($B=C|_A$) that $P\left({(C|_A)}|_A)=P(C|_A) \right)$.

What does that mean ?

${(C|_A)}|_A)$ is the event ''(The second card is spades, given that the first one is spades), given that the first one is spades''.

There is some redundancy here, and it can be seen that ${(C|_A)}|_A)=C|_A$ and therefore $P\left({(C|_A)}|_A)=P(C|_A) \right)$ or

> your event $A$ and your event $B=C|_A$ are independent !

So to summarize:

- If event $A$ is that the first card is spades
- If event $B$ is that the second card is spades conditional on the
  first already being spades
- If event $C$ is that the second card is spades

Then $A$ and $C$ are dependent, but not $A$ and $B$